# Parsing JSON in node.js and displaying in jade

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, pug

I am trying to parse the json and display the response in a table format in jade.
Request your help in parsing the json and displaying the key and value as two columns.

Node.js

```
exports.postMQinput = function(req, res) {
  req.assert('name', 'Queue name field cannot be blank').notEmpty();
  var errors = req.validationErrors();

  if (errors) {
    req.flash('errors', errors);
    return res.redirect('/');
  }

  var options = {
    url: 'URL goes here',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify("my body input comes here")
  }

  request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {            
      res.render('Views/Details', {
        title: 'QUEUE',
        name: 'Welcome',
        result: body
      });
    } else {
      console.log(response.statusCode);
      req.flash('errors', { msg: 'Error during select. Retrying...' });
    }
  })
};
```

My response looks like this.

```
{
  "Response": {
    "data": {
      "length": 123,
      "status": "OPEN"
    }
  }
}
```

Jade :

```
extends ../layout

block content
  .page-header
     h3 MESSAGE QUEUE DETAILS

    table
      thead
    tbody
     table.table.table-striped.table-bordered.table-hover.table-condensed
       tr
        th Value
        th Attribute


      each key, ind in result

        td= "LENGTH"
        td= key.length
        tr
```

I want table something like this

Length    123

Status    Open

Comment: what is the issue youre having?

Comment: I want to display the result in jade in a tabular format which I am not able to do.

Comment: So your issue is you dont know how to display the result in tabular format? Whats the result of the above? What does `key.length` output

Comment: why are you looping through the result. Have you tried `result.data.length` and `result.data.status`?

Comment: AS you mentioned, I tried without looping. I am just getting empty row in the table. The result of my above code was also empty.

Comment: Okay what is `body` exactly? Can you include the code where you define `body`? Have you tried accessing the data step by step? Not in your table but just anywhere on the page to get it to output? Start with `result` and see what that outputs and move onto `result.data` etc.

Comment: @Craicerjack: I have updated my code. Kindly have a look. Yes I tried it step by step as well. I am either getting [object][object] or an empty table. Please help

Comment: if you do a `console.log(body)` right before `res.render('Views/Details', {` what do you get?

Comment: @Craicerjack The console.log(body) is equivalent to the response which I have written in the question.

Comment: if thats the case `result.response.data.length` and `result.response.data.status` should output what youre looking for. Other than that I dont know...

Comment: I already tried it. And was getting the error as cannot read the property data :(

Answer (score 0):

Where the body comes from? Maybe you should run `JSON.parse` on it?

```
res.render('Views/Details', {
        title: 'QUEUE',
        name: 'Welcome',
        result: JSON.parse(body)
});
```

Comment: body is where the response is. I tried JSON.parse as well. But getting [object object]

Answer (score 0):

You are using in a wrong way the iteration to build the HTML from Jade template, I made this example to show you how to use it in case you got an array of values.

```
extends layout

block content
  .page-header
     h3 MESSAGE QUEUE DETAILS

     table.table.table-striped.table-bordered.table-hover.table-condensed
      thead
        tr
          th Value
          th Attribute
      tbody
        for res in result
          for obj in Object.keys(res)
            tr
              td= res[obj]
              td= obj
```

Just in case that you are having a problem with the way you are sending the JSON, take a look to this example:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    return http.get({
        host: 'localhost',
        path: '/json'
    }, function(response) {
        // Continuously update stream with data
        var body = '';
        response.on('data', function(d) {
            body += d;
        });
        response.on('end', function() {
            // Data reception is done, do whatever with it!
            var parsed = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(parsed);
            res.render("index", {result: parsed});
        });
    });

});

app.get('/json', function(req, res){
  var data = [ {
      "length": 123,
      "status": "OPEN"
    },{
    "length": 145,
      "status": "CLOSE"
    }
  ]

  res.json(data);

});

app.listen(80);

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed code. I really appreciate your help on this. But when I follow the method of iteration which you suggested I am not getting the desired output. I am getting it as 


[object object]         data



in a tabular format

Comment: That should be because you are getting and object as a result instead of a key, with this command Object.keys(res) you get all the keys from an Object, so after get the keys, you could get the values from that object easily. 

    for obj in Object.keys(res) // Get all the keys from your Object
    res[obj] // Supposing obj is the key you want to get from your object res

put some code to help you more!